# ffmpeg stuck on last couple of frames during alphamerge

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, alpha-channel

I'm trying to put alpha channel on an mp4 file, using an alpha file that I have previously extracted. The command that I'm using with some tuning flags is this:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i video.mp4 -i alpha.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]alphamerge" -c:v libvpx -c:a libopus -b:v 2900k -crf 40 -pix_fmt yuva420p -threads 32 -auto-alt-ref 0 final_4.webm -loglevel verbose
```

Both the files `video.mp4` and `alpha.mp4` are 4k, 60fps

The issue that I'm facing is this: the whole process works normally until the very last one or two frames, then ffmpeg just hangs indefinitely with this last output `frame=   90 fps=1.2 q=0.0 size=1kB time=00:00:01.49 bitrate=5.4kbits/s speed=0.02x`, no output in verbose or trace mode also.

Surprisingly, this is working for some other videos which are similar to `video.mp4`

`ffprobe video.mp4` outputs this:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2972 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2905 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 70 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

`ffprobe alpha.mp4` outputs this:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'alpha.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 698 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
```

1. Is there a way to add more verbosity to at least know what's going on at this point?
2. Is there any other way I can do this such that it is more reliable and works, unlike this method?

Comment: Needs to be debugged. Can you share both inputs?

Comment: Using -hide_banner is not helpful at all.

Comment: @Gyan I am facing the same issue and can provide input files, should I open a new question?

Comment: Please do. Also share full command and its log.

Comment: @Gyan I posted a new question https://superuser.com/questions/1581797/ffmpeg-hangs-on-last-frame-during-alphamerge